# Run docker .net core 6.0 api

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

When I run the API in Visual Studio the API runs without problems.

After this I make the Image and container for docker:

```
docker image build -t TAG --no-cache .
docker image push TAG
docker container run -d -p:8080:80 --name TAG TAG
```

In docker the container gives me this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not
> found in assembly 'TAG, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 44398

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TAGAPI.csproj", "Services/TAGAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/TAGAPI/TAGAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/TAGAPI"
RUN dotnet build "TAGAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TAGAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TAGAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: I started a new project in .net6 and copied the code and it works